# How to get ONLY COMPLETED orders from woocommerce using SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am getting product order info from various tables. Now I want to get all this info also on the basis of Completed order. i.e order_status should be 'Completed'.

Here is my SQL

```
 SELECT distinct  posts.ID
 FROM   `wp_posts` AS posts,
        `wp_woocommerce_order_items` AS orderitems,
        `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` AS orderitemsmeta, 
        `wp_term_relationships` AS postrel, 
        `wp_terms` AS postterms 
 WHERE    ( orderitemsmeta.order_item_id = orderitems.order_item_id ) 
 AND    ( orderitems.order_id = posts.ID )
 AND    ( postrel.object_id = orderitemsmeta.meta_value )
 AND    ( postrel.term_taxonomy_id <> 4 )
 AND    ( postterms.term_id = postrel.term_taxonomy_id )
 AND    ( posts.post_type = 'shop_order' )  
 AND    ( post_status != 'trash' ) 
 AND    ( post_date > '2015-03-16')
 **//AND (order_status=completed)** //something like this
 ORDER  BY posts.post_date DESC";
```

How to do this?

Any help will be appricaited. Thanks

Comment: Just add a condition for order_status to be like completed?

Comment: yes just wanna add a condition order_status=completed....but dont know how to actually it works

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query for fetch complete order

SELECT distinct posts.ID FROM `wp_posts` AS posts, `wp_woocommerce_order_items` AS orderitems, `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` AS orderitemsmeta, `wp_term_relationships` AS postrel, `wp_terms` AS postterms WHERE ( orderitemsmeta.order_item_id = orderitems.order_item_id ) AND ( orderitems.order_id = posts.ID ) AND ( postrel.object_id = orderitemsmeta.meta_value ) AND ( postrel.term_taxonomy_id <> 4 ) AND ( postterms.term_id = postrel.term_taxonomy_id ) AND ( posts.post_type = 'shop_order' ) AND ( post_status != 'trash' ) AND ( post_date > '2015-03-16') AND (post_status='wc-completed') ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID
FROM wp_posts AS posts
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items AS orderitems ON orderitems.order_id = posts.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS orderitemsmeta ON orderitemsmeta.order_item_id = orderitems.order_item_id 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS postrel ON postrel.object_id = orderitemsmeta.meta_value 
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS postterms ON postterms.term_id = postrel.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE postrel.term_taxonomy_id <> 4
AND posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND post_status != 'trash'
AND post_date > '2015-03-16'
AND order_status = completed
ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: above given sql query also working fine but here's a question what is order_status. it dosnot exist any where

Comment: You will need to review your database schema to see where order_status is used and filter on that

Comment: @RichardNixon you just took his query... and its wrong... the condition will be order_status = 'completed' ... you are comparing two columns in your query

Comment: @Esar-ul-haqQasmi - And what dou you want from us then? When you dont know where you have the value for order_status , how should we know when we cant see your tables?

Answer (score -1):

Got the solution....

```
 SELECT distinct  posts.ID
 FROM   `wp_posts` AS posts,
        `wp_woocommerce_order_items` AS orderitems,
        `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` AS orderitemsmeta, 
        `wp_term_relationships` AS postrel, 
        `wp_terms` AS postterms 
 WHERE    ( orderitemsmeta.order_item_id = orderitems.order_item_id ) 
 AND    ( orderitems.order_id = posts.ID )
 AND    ( postrel.object_id = orderitemsmeta.meta_value )
 AND    ( postrel.term_taxonomy_id <> 4 )
 AND    ( postterms.term_id = postrel.term_taxonomy_id )
 AND    ( posts.post_type = 'shop_order' )  
 AND    ( post_status != 'trash' ) 
 AND    ( post_date > '2015-03-16')
 **AND (post_status='wc-complete')**  
 ORDER  BY posts.post_date DESC";
```

There is also another way to do this that is we can fetch record by **order completed date** from **post_meta** table.